# ActiveRecord .dup on Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models, `Survey` and `Question`. A `Survey` `has_many :questions` and a `Question` `belongs_to :survey`. I know I can duplicate an instance of `Survey` by doing the following:

```
old_survey = Survey.last
new_survey = old_survey.dup
```

Now `new_survey` will be identical to `old_survey` except that its `id` attribute is `nil`. What I would like to know is how I can also duplicate associated objects, preferably without iterating through them or installing a 3rd party gem.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
old_survey = Survey.last
new_survey = old_survey.dup
new_survey.questions = old_survey.questions.dup
old_survey.save!
```

The above code doesn't work. If I call `new_survey.questions.pluck(:id)` I can see that the ids match `old_survey.questions.pluck(:id)`, which is not desirable.

Obviously I could just iterate through `old_survey.questions`, but I'd like to find a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `deep_clonable` gem:
https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable

and then you could do something like this:

```
old_survey.dup include: :questions
```

But that adds another dependency to your app. The easiest way would be be to iterate through the old survey questions and assign ids as necessary. Your question states that you want to avoid doing so, but I really think it's the best (and most light-weight) option.

If you're willing to loop through the associated objects, this should do the trick:

```
def clone_with_questions
  new_survey = self.dup
  new_survey.save
  new_survey.questions = self.questions
  new_survey
end

@new_survey = Survey.last.clone_with_questions
```

Might have to tweak it a bit to work with your app, but that's the general idea.

Comment: `preferably without iterating through them or installing a 3rd party gem.`

Comment: I'd have to (unfortunately) agree. It's not ideal but it does work without adding a dependency.

Comment: FYI - this will break your original associations as `new_survey.questions = self.questions` will move the questions from the old survey to the new one.

Comment: You could use this instead, assuming you're ok looping: `self.questions.each { |q| new_survey.questions << q.dup }`